# error of imoprt tensorflow as tf in python 3.5.2

Tags: tensorflow

I have installed TensorFlow in virtual environment on Ubunut 16.04. when I enter in virtualen by using command "***source ~/tensorflow/bin/activate***" it enters in virtualen. but after that when I enter the command " **import tensorflow as tf**" it gives me the following error 
"***import: not authorized 'tf' @ error/constitute.c/WriteImages/1028.***"
how to solve this..

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you forgot about telling which interpreter to use. Two variants:

1. Add shebang `#!/usr/bin/env python3` at the beginning of you script

**OR**

2. Run script like `python3 my_scripy.py`